# PHP Mailer Attachment validation

Tags: php, phpmailer

Shouldn't this work?

```
 if (
      ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/png") 
      || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpg") 
      || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/zip") 
      || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpeg")                 
      && ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] > 0)  
    ){

      $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['logo']['name']); 

     }
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

If the input `name="logo"` is a file of type png, jpg, jpeg, or zip and there is at least one, send to mail attachment

I've checked everywhere in Stack Overflow for this, and found nothing. All I've found are basic examples on how to send a known image to myself (not very practical).

Comment: ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpeg")                 
      && ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] > 0) execute first what $_FILES["logo"]["type"] > 0

Comment: Those basic examples are all you need - what you're missing is validating that the 'known' image is in fact known, after that your uploaded image *is* a 'known image' and it will work. The PHP docs on handling file uploads are pretty clear. Why would you check that `type > 0` when type is not a numeric value? `!empty()` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there are at least 2 problems:

- Your `AND` condition will never be used as you have a lot of `OR` conditions on the same level;
- You are using the `type` where I assume you want the `size`.

You probably want something like:

```
if (
      (
             ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/png") 
          || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpg") 
          || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/zip") 
          || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpeg")
      )
      && ($_FILES["logo"]["size"] > 0)  
   ) {
```

Comment: You are right. That did escaped me :face palm: However it didn't send. It sent the rest of the email but not the image

Comment: @LOTUSMS Check if you enter the loop and what the return value of the `$mail->AddAttachment()` method is: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment